# What is the Google calendar gadget lifespan?

Tags: google-gadget

Does anyone know how long Google calendar can keep a gadget?

[Here](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/gadgets/sidebar/#google.calendar.getPreferences) we see:

"Tip: Google Calendar will cache your gadget spec for 1 hour."

Does this mean that after an hour Google will download the gadget again (XML config)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google servers will cache your xml file for an hour, so if you're testing a gadget, you'll want to add some random numbers to the end so it reloads the file.

So instead of this:
https://www.google.com/calendar/render

Try this:
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?149

Otherwise, it'll keep that gadget's xml file for an hour. So if you remove it from that url, the gadget will no longer work in one hour or less, depending on when you removed it. For example, if you removed the file one second after Google looked at it, it will take 59min 59 sec for the gadget to longer work. However, if you removed it 45 min after Google looked at the xml file, then it will not work after 15 minutes.

Hope that helps.